# datatable add data variable for each row

Tags: jquery, datatable

I would like to know if it's possible to add a `data()` variable for each rows using the jquery datatables.
It's possible to do it using jquery but i want to know if it's possible to do it using the plugins.
something like that.

```
var t = $('.table').dataTable();
t.row.add([
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
]).draw().data('id', 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom format,I used [fnCreatedRow](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks) .
Further more,for your example you need something like this:

```
var t = $('.table').dataTable({
   "fnCreatedRow": function (row, data, index) {
       $(row).attr("id",1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks will try it out.